# Qual o problema com essa query da minha JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

Esse é um trecho de uma pagina JSP que lista compromissos do usuario logado.Eu não utilizo JSP nem costumo fazer esse tipo de select mas preciso utilizar dessa forma.

```
 <%

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn
                    = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/agendaLogin", "root", "root");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM compromisso where usuario = '" + usuario + "'");
    %>
    <table width="100%" border="1" class="centralizarDireita">   
        <tr>
            <td><b>Titulo</b></td>
            <td><b>Tipo</b></td>
            <td><b>Data</b></td>     
            <td><b>Local</b></td>
            <td><b>Observacao</b></td>

        </tr>
```

Esta dando um erro em + usuario +  do select * from compromisso.Não sei o que pode estar errado.

Comment: Qual erro é exibido?

Comment: Escape as aspas simples com \

Comment: O erro é : "Cannot find symbol variable usuario"

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se a sua variável 'usuario' está setada. Debug e veja o valor dela. Ela deve estar como String, e não como nula.